# scipy.linalg.eig left/right eigenvectors not orthogonal to each other

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

For an eigen-decomposition of a matrix, the left and right eigenvectors should be orthogonal to each other. Using scipy.linalg.eig I tested solving the problem as a standard eigenvalue problem and also as a general eigenvalue problem. The left/right eigenvectors returned for the standard eigenvalue problem are orthogonal to each other, verified by computing their dot products. The left/right eigenvectors returned for the general eigenvalue problem are not orthogonal to each other.

Summary:

**left/right e-vectors ARE NOT orthogonal to each other:**

```
evals, evecs_l, evecs_r = scipy.linalg.eig(M, N, left=True, right=True)
```

**left/right e-vectors ARE orthognal to each other:**

```
evals, evecs_l, evecs_r = scipy.linalg.eig(np.inverse.inv(N) @ M, left=True, right=True)
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg

M = np.array([[1., 2.],
              [4., 5.]])

N = np.array([[0.2, 0.1],
              [0.7, 0.8]])


evals, evecs_l, evecs_r = scipy.linalg.eig(M,N,left=True,right=True)

np.set_printoptions(precision=3,linewidth=200)
print('inner product: GEP')
I = evecs_l.conj().T @ evecs_r
for i in range(I.shape[1]):
    print(I[i,:])


evals, evecs_l, evecs_r = scipy.linalg.eig(np.linalg.inv(N) @ M,left=True,right=True)

print('inner product: SEP')
I = evecs_l.conj().T @ evecs_r
np.set_printoptions(precision=3,linewidth=200)
for i in range(I.shape[1]):
    print(I[i,:])
```

Returns:

```
inner product: GEP
[-0.153 -0.818]
[0.932 0.907]
inner product: SEP
[0.721 0.   ]
[0.    0.721]
```

So, I am wondering if someone could provide insight into this behavior. Am I interpreting the result or expected behavior incorrectly?

System:
Python 3.6.4, numpy 1.14.0, scipy 1.0.0, OS X 10.13.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the regular eigenvalue decomposition, the statement that the left and right eigenvectors are orthogonal can be restated as *the product `evecs_l.conj().T @ evecs_r` is diagonal*.  That statement is not true in general for the generalized eigenvalue problem `Mx = λNx`.  There, it becomes *the product `evecs_l.conj().T @ N @ evecs_r` is diagonal*.  (We need to write `evecs_l.conj().T` instead of just `evecs_l` because `scipy.linalg.eig` returns the conjugate of the left eigenvectors in the columns of the matrix.)

For example,

```
In [38]: M
Out[38]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 4.,  5.]])

In [39]: N
Out[39]: 
array([[ 0.2,  0.1],
       [ 0.7,  0.8]])

In [40]: evals, evecs_l, evecs_r = scipy.linalg.eig(M, N, left=True, right=True)
    ...: 

In [41]: np.set_printoptions(precision=3, linewidth=200, suppress=True)

In [42]: evecs_l.conj().T @ N @ evecs_r
Out[42]: 
array([[ 0.701, -0.   ],
       [ 0.   ,  0.08 ]])
```